# mysql query to check if gender selected all

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Hello In my application I wanted to show the ads to the users depending on the audience selected by the advertiser. at the moment I am saving gender to each user in the user database. The ads work best if the user selects gender male or female. But I don't know how I can modify the query if the user selected all as an audience.

I have two tables. `Promotion` and `audience`. This is how I am querying at the moment

```
 SELECT p.id
      , v.id
      , a.id
      , a.user_id
      , a.name
      , a.min_age
      , a.max_age
      , a.gender
      , a.created 
   FROM promotion p
   LEFT 
   JOIN video v
     ON v.id = p.video_id 
   LEFT 
   JOIN audience a
     ON a.id = p.audience_id 
  WHERE p.user_id != 17 
    AND a.gender = 'Male'
```

what I am intended to do is that if the `gender` value in the Audience table is saved as `all` then It shouldn't check male or female in the query. It should get all the records irrespective of the fact the user is male or female

Comment: I find it very odd to have a *database* called *mytable* - and note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`. For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and note that you have THREE tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
WHERE .... 
    AND `Audience`.`gender` IN ('All', ?)
```

The question mark represents the parameter to the query, that corresponds to the user's gender. It may take value `'Male'` or `'Female'`. If `audience`s stored `gender` is `'All'`, the condition always matches, regardless of the parameter given.

Comment: for the sake of my curiosity: why the `?` ?

Comment: @LelioFaieta: this is explained in the answer. As I understand the question, this is actually is a search parameter, that is passed from the application according to the gender of the user.

Comment: ok, so it's the placeholder for a parametrized query.  got it

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this is what I was looking for. for now, it is working.